# Could not load file or assembly My.Custom.Assembly.dll, Version=1.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def751c98b41d765 or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#-4.0, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, class-library, .net-assembly

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, I wrote one plug-in in C# for Account entity to do some operations on fields when Account record is created. In C# code I created my own custom assembly called My.Custom.Assembly.dll. Which contains some generic methods those I can use often in my plug-in. And I using this My.Custom.Assembly.dll and also added in reference in my project. 
 Project builds successfully and plug-in registration also.
 The problem I faced when I was creating a Account record. Its throwing an error: **"Could not load file or assembly My.Custom.Assembly.dll, Version=1.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def751c98b41d765 or one of its dependencies.The System cannot find the file specified."**
 I got to know the problem is with **My.Custom.Assembly.dll**. Can you please help me to solve this problem..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom assembly cannot be loaded during the execution of your plugin.
Either install it in the GAC or merge it with your plugin assembly.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663103/315862) at [Plugin with references not working on CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6662901/315862)

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start debugging this type of issue is to use Fusion Log Viewer to see the details of how .Net runtime is attempting to load the assembly.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx

Based on what you find in the log post more details if you need additional assitance.

You may also want to read up on [How .net loads Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)

Comment: I'm not getting anything in that Fusion Log Viewer. If it works at run time it should not show anything. Because, we are building a solution in .Net frame work, but not running and taking that .dll file to CRM.

Comment: How are you deploying the dll to CRM?

Comment: Since you are deploying to CRM here is an article on how that should be done from Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309620.aspx#bkmk_deployment

Comment: No problem, if this (or ckellers post) helped to fix your problem, can you selected it as the answer.  Thanks

Comment: I worked on both the suggestions. But I don't know whats the exact solution. I can't do any experiment now, to decide the answer. Any way u ppl helped me a lot. Thankful to both.

Comment: @Charan then please give at least up votes for the answers ;)

Comment: @ckeller: Hey sorry. Vote requires 15 reputation. But still I have 3 only.. :(

Comment: @Charan sry, I didn't thought about that. I've voted on your questions.